# Replace from all words, even if seperated with dash, first character with uppercase [more simple way]

Tags: javascript

I got it working, all variations are displayed `Sint-Anna` as should be, but I wonder, is there a more simple way to this, since it looks very cluttered?

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function(){
    var sa = this.replace(/-/g,' ');
    var saa = sa.toLowerCase();
    var sb = saa.replace( /(^|\s)([a-z])/g , function(m,p1,p2){ return p1+p2.toUpperCase(); } );
    var sc = sb.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
    return sc;
};

console.log('sint-anna'.capitalize());
console.log('sint anna'.capitalize());
console.log('sint-Anna'.capitalize());
console.log('Sint Anna'.capitalize());
console.log('SiNt anna'.capitalize());
console.log('SINT ANNA'.capitalize());
```

Console:

```
Sint-Anna
Sint-Anna
Sint-Anna
Sint-Anna
Sint-Anna
Sint-Anna
```

There are no ways that there is a wrong input like `Si ntAn na` resulting in `Si-Ntan-Na`.

Comment: If this is working code, this is possibly a better fit over on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Better suited to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know this existed. Will do so.

Comment: You have a website to help you [here](http://forwebonly.com/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-a-string-in-javascript-the-fast-way/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function(){
   this.split('-').map(function(str){
      return str[0].toUpperCase() + str.substr(1).toLowerCase();
   }).join("-")  
};
```

The above would be more succinct I suppose. It splits on `-` and then maps, which captializes first letter and lower cases the others and then joins with `-` using `Array.join`

Comment: Faster way is to use `return str[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + capitalizeMe.substring(1)` as a result of many tests [here](http://forwebonly.com/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-a-string-in-javascript-the-fast-way/).

Comment: Do I read this correctly that only words like `sint-anna`get edited, not `sint anna`?

Comment: @lennert_h yes. Since it is being splitted on `-`

Comment: Thanks, I will test with this code then. Normally, there will be no spaces in the words I need to convert, but one never knows.